# Cannot find declaration to go to for assets

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

Most of my assets of my Laravel project are either in `/storage` folder or in the `/public` folder.

In my blade files, I references these asses with `url('/storage/..)`. PhpStorm thinks that those do not exists.

[image]

When I commit, each image will add up to one error.

How can I tell PhpStorm that my assets are indeed in this directory?
I tried to add `storage` folder to `PHP>Laravel>Views/Template` but this doesn't work and I believe I have not fully understood what this path/namespace blade thing is supposed to do.

Comment: where is backgrounds folder ? is it in storage/app/public/backgrounds ?

Comment: @JohnLobo yes its in `storage/app/public/backgrounds`

Comment: @Adam You have solved it, great. Just a note: those original paths should still have worked (be recognized) in PhpStorm. 1) As I understand you have `public/storage` symlink already created, right? 2) How the `public` folder is handled in PhpStorm? Did you marked it as "Resource Root"? You need that if you want for absolute URLs (that start with `/`) to be recognized relative to the `public` and not PROJECT_ROOT folder...

Comment: @LazyOne I do have the symlink created and the assets are shown in browser. "public" is marked as resource root. But I still see the error message in PHPStorm. Whats also odd, the "storage" folder is correctly found, but it looks that it only starts not working for "backgrounds". Maybe the issue is because I created the symlink inside the docker container?

Comment: @Adam *"Maybe the issue is because I created the symlink inside the docker container?"* Sadly cannot comment on this. It just I have it all local (Windows 10), done as the above (symlink + Resource Root) and any URLs that I'm referencing with `/storage/...` are getting resolved correctly for me in SCSS and Blade/HTML files (I even have `PROJECT_ROOT/storage` is marked as Excluded...). Don't know what else to say here. Maybe it's some interference from a plugin? If so -- just try disabling all custom plugins and restart the IDE -- any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the asset helper

```
style="background-image: url('{{ asset('storage/backgrounds/lavender') }}');">dfsdf</div>
```

Comment: And I guess it makes sense to define `ASSET_URL=/storage` and only use `asset('backgrounds/lavender')` in case I want to move my assets to another host some day.

Comment: I prefer to use custom file system entries for that, and write my own helper

Comment: I think it makes sense to leave it to your environment settigs where you host your assets and not hardcode in a custom helper. But anyway, `asset`was the correct choice here.

Answer (score 1):

do command this

```
php artisan storage:link
```

> will create shortcut folder in public/storage to path storage/app/public

ineasted of `url('/storage/..)` to `public_path('storage/....')`

Comment: This would not work, as `public_path` would return the hardcoded path to the public folder, meaning `public/storage/...` this could not be parsed on the client side.

Comment: public_path can never be used in the context of client-side code.  Paths are for code, URIs are for client facing stuff

Comment: You confuse url() with the php function.  In this case it is a css property

Comment: use public_path inside {{ }} for blade engine to get public path whereever url

Comment: url get all string of url with paramertes and pages

Comment: public_path gives you the _path_ of the public folder.  it is no use when you want a url.  url in this question is CSS property for background. Not the url php function.